# How can I loop td_i.innerHTML = message;

Tags: javascript

My code.

```
td_0.innerHTML = message;
td_1.innerHTML = message;
td_2.innerHTML = message;
```

How can I loop to this?

```
for (var i = 0; i < VarNames.length; i++) {
    td_i.innerHTML = message;
}
```

Comment: Those shouldn't be standalone variables - put them in an array or an object instead, and then iterate over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm blindly answering the question without helping the real goal behind the ask but just for reference, it is possible to loop some global variable names via the `window` object:

```
for (var i = 0; i < VarNames.length; i++) {
    window[`td_${i}`].innerHTML = message;
}
```

The above code is just to show looping over variables that contains a variable in their names. I wouldn't do it in real code. Like other answers mentioned, it's better to get your elements into an iterable object with `querySelectorAll()`, so you don't have to declare individual variables for each element.

Answer (score 2):

May be the following can help you out:

```js
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td')
var message = 'Test Data';
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    tds[i].innerHTML =  message + i;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table id="tableID">
<tr>
<td>my td</td>
</tr>
</table>

var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   //iterate through rows
   //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
   for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
     //iterate through columns
     //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
        col.innerHTML = message;
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and then [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('#tableID tr td')
  .forEach((td, i) => td.innerHTML = 'Element ' + i);
```

```html
<table id="tableID">
  <tr>
    <td>td 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>td 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>td 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```